# Duda sobre insertar elementos a una lista tipo cola

Tags: java

estoy aprendiendo java y llegué a este tema. El código que voy a mostrar funciona, lo copié y pegué de un tutorial, pero no entiendo algo:\

```
 public void Insertar(int informacion){
        Nodo nuevo_nodo = new Nodo();
        nuevo_nodo.informacion = informacion;
        nuevo_nodo.siguiente = null;
        
        if (ColaVacia()) {
            inicioCola = nuevo_nodo;
            finalCola = nuevo_nodo;
        } else {
            System.out.println(inicioCola.siguiente);
            finalCola.siguiente = nuevo_nodo;
            System.out.println(inicioCola.siguiente);
            System.out.println(finalCola.siguiente);
            finalCola = nuevo_nodo;
        }
    }
```

Los system.out.print los agregué yo para ver qué "valores" tienen esos objetos, se imprime lo siguiente
null
clases.Nodo@543c6f6d
clases.Nodo@543c6f6d

En el else{} imprimo inicioCola.siguiente e imprime null, pero después de pasarle a finalCola.siguiente el valor de nuevo_nodo, también se modifica el valor de inicioCola.siguiente y causalmente vale exactamente lo mismo que finalCola.siguiente ¿Por qué pasa eso?

Comment: La razón por la que muestra esos valores es porque hay un solo elemento en la cola y todavía no se actualizó la referencia de **finalCola**,  es decir **finalCola = nuevoNodo** . Agregá con dos elementos en la cola y fijate que pasa.

Comment: Hola @LucasRox ,no sé si no entendí bien tu respuesta.Consulto algo parecido
Al insertar un segundo elemento, inicioCola y finalCola son iguales, o eso es lo que me da a entender la ejecución del programa. Pero¿son el mismo objeto o son objetos distintos que tenían los mismos atributos antes de que los modificara? Pareciera ser que al modificar algún atributo de finalCola, también se modifica ese mismo atributo de inicioCola(al menos al insertar el segundo elemento, cuando llega al tercer elemento los atributos de inicioCola no se modifican nunca más hasta que se extraen elementos de la cola)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que ocurre con tu código es:

Cuando hay un solo elemento

```
Nodo A = (un valor, sig = null)
cola:  A -> null
Inicio -> dir A
Final -> dir A
```

(a través de Inicio y Final accedes al nodo al que hacen referencia en este caso es el mismo )

Ejecución de el código:

1 - Imprime el valor de Inicio.siguiente = *null*.

2 - Final.siguiente = nuevo_nodo

```
Nodo A = (un valor, sig = nuevo_nodo) // modifico siguiente
Nodo B = (un valor, sig = null) // este es el nuevo nodo
cola:  A -> B -> null
Inicio -> dir A
Final -> dir A
```

3 - Imprime el valor de Inicio.siguiente = *dir de nuevo_nodo*.

4 - Imprime el valor de Final.siguiente = *dir de nuevo_nodo*.

(en este punto todavía no se actualizó Final por lo que Final.siguiente muestra la misma dirección que Inicio.siguiente).

5 - Final = nuevo_nodo :

```
Nodo A = (un valor, sig = nuevo_nodo).
Nodo B = (un valor, sig = null) // este es el nodo nuevo.
cola:  A -> B -> null.
Inicio -> dir A.
Final -> dir B. // dirección actualizada
```

En este punto Final tienen la dirección del nodo B y Final.siguiente es null.
*Nota: Inicio es inicioCola y Final es finalCola.*

Debo aclarar que inicioCola y finalCola, tienen la dirección del primero y el último nodo respectivamente y nos permiten acceder a sus campos, cuando la cola está vacía ambos son null y cuando la cola tiene un solo elemento ambos tienen la dirección (referencia) del mismo Nodo (A). Cuando hay más elementos inicioCola tiene la dirección del primero(A) y finalCola la dirección del último (B).

Es un tema difícil de explicar por este medio, es más fácil de entender con lápiz y papel y dibujando como se modifica la cola y como cambian las referencias. El momento en que haces las impresiones confunde más de la que aclara. Saludos

Comment: Entendí perfectamente, muchísimas gracias <3